Ability to set and retrieve New Altered Content Disclosure Flag
Is it possible to access, or edit the new Altered Content flag for videos?
Can't seem to recover the data using listVideos, or see anywhere in the documentation that I can set it on upload.
I expect to be able to set this flag on Upload.
print_r($youtubeService->videos->listVideos("contentDetails,fileDetails,status,topicDetails,snippet", array('id' => $videoId)) );

doesn't display anything related to the disclosure.

Feature documentation: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/14328491?hl=en
altered and synthetic do not appear in YouTube Data API v3 revision history, hence it does not seem officially supported. Your best luck is web-scraping.

I don't really want to see it..
I have a client who uses our platform to upload hundreds of videos a week, and they have to manually go set this setting for each video... It would be much easier if it was something that could be set via the API, there seem to be quite a few of these types of settings showing up over the last few years.
